# Trying to filter a DataSet in R: Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, filter, closures

Veeery basic question where I found no matching answer in other Topics. I read about problems as data.frames and functions...doesn't seem to apply here?

I'd like to filter in a specific csv-dataSet(cut) a random row and column. (cut is the name of a specifc amount of Columns via select-function. That worked)

My code:
filtered_data <- filter[cut, 3, 5]

My result
Error in filter[cut, 3, 5] :
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

As you can imagine, I'd like to get the specific value back in return, but it didnT't happen.
I assume it might be the csv, which is a statistic in the german police crime data base called "PKS"
Maybe the way it was formatted is the reason for the error.

Don't know if it helps, but to read it I need to use "read_csv2('df') for the , which are changed in ;

Since I need to write a paper using this data with ggplot etc. I need to filter this huge csv. down to my needs to create and plot...

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Explain in words, what you think each element of you code is doing.

Comment: `cut` is the name of a function in base R.  Change the name of your object and it may work.